# How to best possibly protect .m file?

Tags: matlab

I have an .m file which I wish to share with my friends but I am not interested in giving .m file. Could someone help me with best possible ways to convert it to a file that is not decodable? 
I tried converting it to .p file by simply typing pcode example.m
however I don't believe it is really protecting it. I was able to convert my .p file back to .m file with the following link. https://sites.google.com/site/sippeyfunlabs/matlab-hacks/please-do-not-secure-your-password-in-matlab-p-code

This actually confirms that my code is not protected.

It'll be nice if someone shares the best methodology to protect .m file and sharing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://sites.google.com/site/sippeyfunlabs/matlab-hacks/please-do-not-secure-your-password-in-matlab-p-code) you provided yourself already indicates that it is very difficult to obfuscate MATLAB code:

> In fact, MATLAB language is very difficult to be secured or even obfuscated. 
>   This is due to the late binding (or dynamic binding) feature of
>   MATLAB. [...] The amount of meta information associated with this
>   feature basically forbid any attempt of adding code level security.
>   Simply put, if there is a MATLAB file, and it calls a function foo
>   inside it. Until the runtime, the MATLAB interpreter do not even know
>   if foo is a function stored in M file or a built-in function or a mex
>   function or even a workspace function handle. Thus, it must store foo
>   as is somewhere inside the generated P-code.

Also to best solution is already mentioned on that page:

> If there is really a need to do this, using the good old binary is a
>   much better solution. Or you can put critical code on a server, away
>   from the user.

- Create a binary, i.e. mex file (see the answer of Wolfie): Note that to some extent also binary code can be decompiled especially small ones.
- **Host your code on a server** (and run the code server-side): This is the best method to protect your code. You should let the user upload the input for your script and return the result. You can also automatize this process using a matlab script to make this process transparent to the user.

Comment: @m7913d: Thank you for the discussion. How shall we do the way that you mentioned? Like uploading the input and download the result. could you please explain more to actually implement. Thanks

Comment: @KGV It is not an easy/straight forward solution, but consists of (1) creating a webpage which accepts user input, (2) a server with an installed matlab version and optionally (3) creating a matlab script to upload the input data and download the response. I think it is too broad to explain it completely in a single post, but you should be able to find all the relevant pieces on the web to implement this method.

Comment: @KGV No problem. Your follow up question would be too broad for this site *even if it was a completely new question*! You would need a server, some sort of client-side interface (webpage/API) for input, and quite a bit of code to get it working. If it isn't completely overkill for your  purposes then you'd need to do some learning and start a new question with specific issues if you need more help here. In the meantime I'd probably accept m7913d's answer :)

Comment: Note that also @Wolfie's answer deserves some upvotes as it may be a good trade off between ease of implementation and protecting your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could [build a mex file](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-mex-files.html).

This will completely obfuscate your actual MATLAB code, since it will be written in C/C++/FORTRAN, but the algorithms will still be there if your *friends* are determined enough to look for them.